# PowerBI cannot convert value null to type logical when adding custom column

Tags: powerbi

Trying to make a custom column dependant on a column that consists of numerical values and null values (for bad data).
My expression:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if [Value] > 0.5 then 100 else if [Value] = "null" then "null" else 80)
```

I get the error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical.

Any suggestions? Spoofing the nulls to 0 will make my data confusing for values that may indeed be 0.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just bring your **null** checking to the front as below-

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if [Value] = null then null else if [Value] > 0.5 then 100 else 80)
```

for more details, [go here](http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2018/05/17/comparing-null-values-in-power-query/)